# I forget to record the physical disk sequence for MegaRAID before transfer. Is there any way to recover.

Tags: raid, megaraid

I was so careless when I send my server for repairing. I removed disks from chassis to protect the data, but I did not record the position sequence for each disk and my raid card failed to build RAID5 after I changed the sequence for my current disk position. Is there any way to read out the disk sequence of rebuild the RAID without loosing the data?

Its is better to tell me a way by using MegaCLI because WebBIOS is stuck after this issue.

Thanks